# ROR + NoMethodError (Attempt to call private method) in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my code "

> NoMethodError (Attempt to call private
>   method):
>   app/controllers/project_evaluations_controller.rb:94:in
>   `calculate'"

occurs.
SampleCode : For Controller :: Index & Show Method is not mentioned.

```
class ProjectEvaluationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:index, :show]
  def calculate
    @project_id = params[:id]
    @costs_last_calculated = Time.now.utc
    @total_internal_hours = 10
    @total_external_hours = 20
    @project_evaluation.update(:internal_hours => @total_internal_hours, :external_hours => @total_external_hours, :costs_last_calculated => @costs_last_calculated)
        render :action=>"show"
  end
end
```

Routes :

```
  resources :project_evaluations do
      match "calculate", :on => :collection
    end
```

Suggest any solution !!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`update` is a private method for Active Record objects in Rails. You want to use `update_attributes` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Where does @project_evaluation come from?  Is the `update` method there something you defined?  That doesn't exist as a method on instances of ActiveRecord (at least publicly) so it's possible it thinks you are trying to call a private method of that name, defined in ActiveRecord::Base somewhere.  That's the main thing I see that's going on in there that looked wrong.  I would change it to `@project_evaluation.update_attributes()` instead.